# Java Spring Boot Logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

Is there a way to print a different `logging.pattern` given a specific `logging.level`?

The yml file I'm using in my Spring Boot project looks like this

```
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix: warn
    org.springframework: warn
    org.apache: warn
    org.mongodb: warn
    com.twocatholler: debug
  pattern:
    console: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %white([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %white(%logger) - %white(%msg) %n"
```

Answer (score 2):

If having multiple appenders is acceptable, a straightforward way to have different patterns for different levels would be using two different appenders with [ThresholdFilters](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter).

Answer (score 1):

There can be issues when more appenders are writing to the same file. Check this issue for example: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-114

However, you can have your own appender which formats logging events differently, based on their level.

Check this LevelPatternLayout demo: https://github.com/riskop/logback_LevelPatternLayout

example logback.xml:

```
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="pack.LevelPatternLayout">
                <defaultPattern>DEFAULT PATTERN %c - %m\n</defaultPattern>
                <debugPattern>DEBUG PATTERN %c - %m\n</debugPattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

test code:

```
public void test() throws Exception{
    log.debug("some debug level log");
    log.info("some info level log");
    log.error("some error level log");
}
```

output:

```
DEBUG PATTERN pack.TestStart - some debug level log
DEFAULT PATTERN pack.TestStart - some info level log
DEFAULT PATTERN pack.TestStart - some error level log
```

LevelPatternLayout code:

```
package pack;

import java.util.HashMap;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.LayoutBase;

/**
 * A logback layout which can be configured with different pattern for different levels.
 * 
 * E.g. you can configure a pattern for DEBUG messages and an *other* pattern
 * for INFO messages and so on. 
 * 
 *
 */
public class LevelPatternLayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private boolean started;

    // store for patternLayouts per level. The layout stored with 'null' key is the fallback
    private HashMap<Level, PatternLayout> layouts = new HashMap<>();

    public LevelPatternLayout() {
    }

    public void setDefaultPattern(String pattern) {
        setLevelPattern(null, pattern);
    }

    public void setTracePattern(String pattern) {
        setLevelPattern(Level.TRACE, pattern);
    }

    public void setDebugPattern(String pattern) {
        setLevelPattern(Level.DEBUG, pattern);
    }

    public void setInfoPattern(String pattern) {
        setLevelPattern(Level.INFO, pattern);
    }

    public void setWarnPattern(String pattern) {
        setLevelPattern(Level.WARN, pattern);
    }

    public void setErrorPattern(String pattern) {
        setLevelPattern(Level.ERROR, pattern);
    }

    private void setLevelPattern(Level level, String pattern) {
        PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
        layout.setContext(context);
        layout.setPattern(pattern);
        layouts.put(level, layout);
    }

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        PatternLayout matchingLayout = layouts.get(event.getLevel());
        if(matchingLayout != null) {
            return matchingLayout.doLayout(event);
        }
        return layouts.get(null).doLayout(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if(layouts.get(null) == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("default layout is not initialized, probably no 'defaultPattern' is configured!");
        }
        layouts.values().forEach(layout -> layout.start());
        this.started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        layouts.values().forEach(layout -> layout.stop());
        this.started = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

}
```